# How to create time slots of the day in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize in advance if you think the question has already been answered, I searched on Stack, but similar answers were much too complex for me.

I have this request in SQL :

```
SELECT dbo.tbTransaction.dateHeure, dbo.tbPoste.nomPoste
FROM dbo.tbTransaction 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbPoste ON dbo.tbTransaction.ID_poste = dbo.tbPoste.ID_POSTE
WHERE dbo.tbPoste.id_site LIKE 17 
AND dbo.tbPoste.nomPoste LIKE 'POSTE1'
AND dateHeure >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0)
ORDER BY dateHeure DESC
```

[image: result]
It gives me all the production of the day, the problem is : it's not precise enough because there is a team shift in the afternoon and another team shift in the night.
If you see all the production of the day, you cannot see which team produced what.
I would like to create 3 different queries that allow me to see only the production between certain hours (for example, production between 6am and noon). Do you have any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What do you mean by sampla data ?
As desired results I want :
Query one : show the rows in the db between 6:00 and 12:00
Query two : show the rows in the db between 12:01 and 19:00
Query three : show the rows in the db between 19:01 and 23:59
Currently I have a single query who shows me every rows in the db of the current day and it's not precise enough.

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to show what data you are getting and what data you want. Pictures don't work very well. I'm guessing you might just be looking for and outer join to a calendar table but not sure what the problem really is

Comment: I'm getting all raws from the current day, I want all raws from the current day between two hours (ex : between 6:00 and 13:00).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to hardcode your time slots. For example you know that morning shift is going to work from 06:00 to 12:00.

As you know the hours, you can use HOUR function on your datetime column with appropriate >, <, = and AND operators to get the required results.

From what I have understood, it should be something like this:

HOUR(datetime column) >= 6 AND HOUR (datetime column) < 12

Comment: I tried but  "HOUR is not a recognized built-in function name"

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to find the query I wanted :

```
SELECT dbo.tbTransaction.dateHeure, dbo.tbPoste.nomPoste FROM dbo.tbTransaction  INNER JOIN dbo.tbPoste ON dbo.tbTransaction.ID_poste = dbo.tbPoste.ID_POSTE WHERE dbo.tbPoste.id_site LIKE 17
AND dbo.tbPoste.nomPoste LIKE 'POSTE1'
AND dateHeure >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0)
AND DATEPART(HOUR, dateHeure) > 6
AND DATEPART(HOUR, dateHeure) < 13
ORDER BY dateHeure DESC
```